# Unable to reference slot props inside template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, vue-script-setup, vue-typescript

I get the following warning in the browser when I try to reference the slot props. What am I missing?

[Vue warn]: Property "disabled" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

This is a link to a sandbox. The error is reproduced here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elated-star-7x6wd9?file=%2Fapp.vue%3A1%2C1

```
//Usage
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
   <MenuItem
          :disabled="true"
          v-slot="{ disabled }"
          :class="{ 'bg-slate-400 text-white': disabled }"
        >
        Item 1
        </MenuItem>
</template>
```

And this is the implementation of the MenuItem component.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Component } from 'vue'

export interface MenuListItemProps {
  as?: string | Component
  disabled?: boolean
}
export interface MenuListItemSlots {
  default(props: { disabled: boolean }): any
}

withDefaults(defineProps<MenuListItemProps>(), {
  as: 'li',
  disabled: false
})

defineSlots<MenuListItemSlots>()



const itemref = ref<HTMLElement | null>()


</script>

<template>
  <component
    :is="as"
    role="menuitem"
    tabindex=-1
    ref="itemref"
    :disabled="disabled"
  >
    <slot
      name="default"
      :disabled="disabled" //slot prop is being provided here
    />
  </component>
</template>
```

I was expecting the disbaled slot prop to be accessible on the class binding. However when i try to access that as shown in the code. I do get a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't understand why the usage above won't work. I figured a way around it.

```
<MenuItem
      :disabled="true"
      v-slot="{ disabled }"
    >
    <span :class="{ 'bg-slate-500 text-white': disabled, 'block': true }">
      Item 3
    </span>
</MenuItem>
```

I'm thinking perhaps you can't use slot props on the component providing those props. You can only use the slot props on elements or components inside the slot content.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `disabled` as you want.

Slots variables are available inside of slot.

explanation from guide: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots

Comment: Thanks for taking a moment to help. I have made corrections to my code. you can still reproduce with just that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).